# Automatic displace subviews in UIView

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiview, subview, transformation

I have 3 subviews subView1,subView2,subView3.

subView1 has dynamic size.
subView2 and subView3 have fixed size.

[image: My situation]

How to automatic displace subView2 and subView3 according to subView1 with standart ios framwork methods?

Comment: Distance between all subViews is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you set the required size for subView1, get its `frame.origin.y` add some offset to it and set subView2's `frame.origin.y` to it. After that add the frame's height + the same offset and use it for subView3.

e.g.

```
// after you've set your subView1's size
CGFloat offset = 20.0;
CGRect s1Frame = [subView1 frame];
CGRect s2Frame = [subView2 frame];
CGRect s3Frame = [subView3 frame];

s2Frame.origin.y = s1Frame.origin.y + s1Frame.size.height + offset;
[subView2 setFrame:s2Frame];

s3Frame.origin.y = s2Frame.origin.y + s2Frame.size.height + offset;
[subView3 setFrame:s3Frame];
```